# Deserialize XML objects based on others

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I wonder if there is a simple way of deserializing xml files to larger objects without the need to specify each element again. So I want xml elements to be based on other elements of the same type and only specify the differences.

Example class:

```
ClassA
{
    [XmlElement("val1")]
    public AnySerializableObject val1;
    [XmlElement("val2")]
    public AnySerializableObject val2;
    [XmlElement("val3")]
    public AnySerializableObject val3;
}
```

Example XML contents:

```
<classA id="object1">
  <val1>anything</val1>
  <val2>whatever</val2>
  <val3>important</val3>
</classA>
<classA id="object2" template="object1">
  <val3>not really important</val3>
</classA>
```

Simple serializing makes two ClassA objects:

```
object1: val1 = anything, val2 = whatever, val3 = important  
object2: val1 = null, val2 = null, val3 = not really important
```

Is there a simple way to read the xml file so object2 uses values of object1 which are not specified?

So it'd be

```
object2: val1 = anything, val2 = whatever, val3 = not really important
```

Or do I have to write my own Serializer which seems to be quite complex?

Comment: What's the aim here? - just to make the XML more compact, or is there some other reason why this would be preferable for you?

Comment: Chaning just one value instead of multiple times would be much easier and the file has better readability.

Comment: How about writing an XSL transform to convert from the full to compact form and vice versa?

Comment: This would probably work but seems to be almost the same effort writing such a script as writing my own serlaiizer. I've started writing my own already and it's working the way I want and is almost finished. Took me about 15 hours.
But thanks for your help!